# (Python) Send structured packet over network

Tags: python, sockets, telepathy-python

i want to build a chat application which supports text messaging, group messaging, file transfer(like netmeeting). when i send it over TCP socket i saw that data is not structured all the data send as string over TCP. I want to send it in a structured way with few headers like name:,ip:,data:,data_type_flag:(file or text message) etc... one stackoverflow  member told me to use TELEPATHY but i can't get a simple tutorial to understand. how can i send structured data over socket? or can any one suggest me a good tutorial to implement telepathy properly. i want to communicate over network as peer-to-peer rather than dedicated server.. Thanks

Comment: what about this http://raphael.slinckx.net/files/telepathy-guadec-2007.pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [google protcol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [apache thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). There are many examples for how to use them.

As for your comment about "peer to peer", please realize that even in peer-to-peer one of the peers is always acting as a server (sometimes both are).

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a [transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer) protocol, as opposed to application layer. This means that TCP is not responsible for the *types* of data you send, only the raw bits. HTTP has headers and other metadata because it is application level.

For a project like the one you're talking about, you will want to implement your own application layer protocol, but this is not exactly a trivial task. I would look at the python source code in the [httplib module](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) for an example of how to implement such a protocol, but note that this is likely fairly different still from what you want, as you will want persistent socket connections to be a first-class citizen in a peer-to-peer chat protocol like the one you're describing.

Another option is to use one of the various RPC libraries, eg [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html), which will handle a decent amount of the required low-level network things for you (although not file transfer; there are other libraries like the [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html?highlight=ftp#module-ftplib) that can do this).

Answer (score 0):

Pickle your data before you send it, and unpickle it on the other end? 
http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Comment: Super dependent on the version of Python.