# Convert file into string then Rebuild that String and make it a file again

Tags: python, string, file, rebuild

I want to send files over the network, however all the tools and commands that was proposed to me wont allow me to automate the process.

Now I remember there's a function in java which allows you to  convert the file into json base64 string, then this string will be sent over the network, then the machine that will receive this will rebuild this into file.

I wonder if I could do that kind of stuff in python?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @Brian - Actually it was stated in the 2nd paragraph. I have a file (of different types) and I want to convert this into string, send this string over the network, then the machine who will receive this will rebuild this string into file again. I wonder if I could it in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, reading a file and writing a file are easy:

```
#read from a file
with open("path/to/file", "rb") as read_file:
    contents = read_file.read()
#write to a file
with open("path/to/file", "wb") as write_file:
    write_file.write(contents)
```

and for base64 encoding, look at the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html)

sending data over a connection is simple enough, and you can do it in many methods - i am not going to solve it here, but i will give you a list of methods you can use:

- the python socket module, [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)
- another post about data: [(Python) Send structured packet over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933207/python-send-structured-packet-over-network)

here is an example using socket from http://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

Comment: It seems that the first solution that you've given is applicable only to text files ?(Read from a file&& write to a file)  I would like to clarify that I want to convert files of different type, which includes apk, exe, etc. Thank you :)

Comment: you can optionally add a `b` to make the file read bytes or write bytes. this is all basic python, and easy to find on a quick google search.

Comment: Please use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement when opening files.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost yes, i usually do but it appears this is a new python user, i didnt want to confuse with complexities, but i will make the edit for prosperity.